# Is there is any way to identify background of an image (indoor or outdoor)

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network

I am doing a research on object identification. I did it using tensorflow and it identified objects of an image well. It does not, however, have any idea how to identify the background of an image (indoor or outdoor).

Comment: Normally on photos the foreground is sharper while the background is more blurry - have you tried using that?

Comment: label data with indoor and outdoor and train your model to distinguish it, should be pretty straight forward for modern vision models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like for each image, you're interested in two classification results: what object appears in the image, and whether it's outdoors or indoors.

A straightforward way of doing that would be to train and apply two different classifiers, one for object recognition and one for background classification.

Getting some images for training shouldn't be difficult, as there are many datasets having exlicitly indoor or outdoor scenes (e.g. [here](http://web.mit.edu/torralba/www/indoor.html)). However depending on your specific data, e.g. specific scenery, colors or light conditions, this may or may not yield good results.